# Change all instances of a number within large CSV file with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, data-cleaning

I am working on a file with large amounts of data and am using NumPy to work with the data. I am trying to change all instances of 99.0 in the 3rd row only to be replaced with np.nan. Basically I need all values of 99.0 within the 3rd row to equal np.nan instead. Currently I have this but it doesnt work:

```
for column in births:
    if births.loc[3, 'ESTGEST'] == 99.0:
        births.loc[3,'ESTGEST'] = births.loc[3,'ESTGEST'].replace({99.0, np.nan})
```

I tried looping through each column of data and searching for 99.0 in that row and replacing it with np.nan instead

Comment: using equality on floats is usually a bad idea, consider using `np.isclose` to get the row that do equal 99 then change them.

Comment: good point, just fixed that. Still doesn't work though

Comment: in the second line you are still replaceing `99.0` which won't happen ... just put `= np.nan` ...

Comment: Like this =         births.loc[3,'ESTGEST'] = births.loc[3,'ESTGEST'].replace({np.nan}) ?